# ILNumerics documentation

Tags: c#, plot, ilnumerics

I'm looking for examples in ILNumerics documentation. I found the [api](http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/Index.html), and [documentation](http://ilnumerics.net/docs.html) but the first is just the class docs and the second is very lacking in examples and cookbooks. Is such a resource anywhere to be found?

Specially for plotting/matrix creation.

Thanks!
PS: I can actually do 2d and 3d plots with for example panel.Graphs.AddSurfGraph(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i], null); but I got this from experimentation.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic*

Comment: I agree but they specifically refer to SO as their support medium, so I was hoping for some actual examples as answers. I'll guess i'll have to write them directly.

Comment: @facuq While products are free to refer users to SO for answers to questions if they want, it in no way makes the standards of this site any more lax.  If they want questions to be answered that don't meet the sites (rather strict) standards, then they'll need to provide that support themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following links: http://ilnumerics.net/plotting-api.html,
http://ilnumerics.net/Arrays.html, http://ilnumerics.net/ArrayCreation3.html? Are you using the latest version (3.2.2) of ILNumerics?

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking again from another computer and the examples now do show; apparently those sample plots are so cpu intensive when rendered in js that when I killed the script I couldn't see any code because the code is shown via js after rendering. I'm sorry for the mixup. You can of course close/delete the question as you see fit, I'll be notifying the ILNumerics team.

Comment: ILNumerics confirms the problem, they kindly emailed me the [pdf documentation](http://www.mediafire.com/?qqb6vz5p2tsvd5p)